# How do I check if CPUID.(EAX=14H, ECX=0)?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86, cpuid

According to the intel reference manual the instruction throws a #UD exception if `CPUID.(EAX=14H, ECX=0):EBX.PTWRITE [Bit 4] = 0`

How do I check these values?

If I use `int __get_cpuid (unsigned int __level, unsigned int *__eax, unsigned int *__ebx, unsigned int *__ecx, unsigned int *__edx)` from `<cpuid.h>` then what should be the arguments?

Answer (score 5):

You can't use that. You need a version where you can pass in `ecx` too since that has to be zero. You can use `__cpuid_count` if available, for example:

```c
unsigned eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
if (__get_cpuid(0x00, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx) == 0) {
    // cpuid not supported
}
if (eax < 0x14) {
    // leaf 0x14 not supported
}
__cpuid_count(0x14, 0x00, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
if ((ebx & 0x10) == 0) {
    // PTWRITE not supported
}
```

Comment: Please fix it. It should be: ((ebx & 0x10) == 0)
I spent days figuring out why my code is giving me an illegal instruction exception even though it is supported. Finally compiled your code with a different compiler and it gave me a warning about operator precedence. lol

Comment: Oops, sorry about that.

Comment: In gcc 6.4.1 the header `cpuid.h` defines a function `__get_cpuid_count()`, and an inline assembly macro `__cpuid_count`. I dunno what was there in 2016, but for a recent gcc you need to call `__get_cpuid_count()` (or properly setup an inline assembly statement).